# 7Zip - Zipping 50 files at a time in a folder to separate zip files

Tags: batch, zip, 7-zip

I've got a folder of 1000 files. I would like to set-up a batch using 7Zip so it will zip 50 files using a separate zip each time.

e.g
File 1-50
1.7zip or 1.zip
File 51-100
2.7zip or 2.zip

Is it possible to this in 7Zip at all?

Comment: Try this page here at SuperUser https://superuser.com/questions/1188394/using-a-batch-file-to-zip-files-as-individual-zip-files

Comment: It's possible, but what have you tried up to now?

Comment: Sorry, I've looked at various stacks examples but none of them specifically help with what I'm looking for.